# Service instance data in Livewire doesn't persist

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, service, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component called `BooksComponent`.

And I have a service class called `BooksService`.

I want the `BooksComponent` in the lifecycle `mount` method to use the `BooksService` to `set` a `$books` array into the `BookService`.

Then I want `BooksComponent` to again use the `BooksService` to get the books array from the `BooksService` when a method is called after a **button** **click**.

The **Problem** is: the `BookService` `$books` array is set on `mount`, but when I want to `get` the `$books` array it loses the `$books` data.

My code looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Services\BooksService;

class BooksComponent extends Component
{
    public array $books;

    public function mount(BooksService $booksService)
    {
        $booksService->setBooks(['book1', 'book2', 'book3']); //this works ok
    }

    public function handleClick(BooksService $booksService)
    {
        $this->books = $booksService->getBooks(); // here is the problem: getBooks returns empty array
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.books-component');
    }
}
```

```blade
<div>
    <button wire:click.prevent="handleClick">Get Books</button>
    <div>
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <li>{{ $book }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class BooksService
{

    private array $books;   

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = [];
    }

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function setBooks($books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }
}
```

I also tried to create a `BooksServiceProvider` and make it return a `BooksService` **singleton** instance using the `register` method but it didn't work. I always get an empty array.

So **Laravel** and **Livewire** experts what are your thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Livewire doc](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties):
`Properties can ONLY be either JavaScript-friendly data types (string, int, array, boolean), OR one of the following PHP types: Stringable, Collection, DateTime, Model, EloquentCollection.` 
So unfortunately, you can't make an object persist (except for the mention supported types).

**But, if you serialize your object after assignment, it gets converted to string and can travel as a public property of the component which persists.**

Here's how you do it:

```
public array $books;

public string $bookService;

public function mount(BooksService $booksService)
{
    $booksService->setBooks(['book1', 'book2', 'book3']);
    $this->bookService = serialize($booksService); // this serializes bookService and converts it into a string
}

public function handleClick(BooksService $booksService)
{
    $booksService = unserialize($this->booksService); // unserialises and converts bookService back to the object
    $this->books = $booksService->getBooks();
}
```

Though it is dangerous to have a serialized string exposed to the browser (since it is exposed to modification), Livewire has this checksum verification to ensure that if a request is tempered, it rejects that request